# Updating a value for the session user?

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I made a function that is supposed to, when run, update the chapter value of the session user only, to 1, this is what I made and stored in a file called **chapcomp.php**:

```
<?php
$con = (my connection info is here)

$sql = "UPDATE users
SET chapter= '1'
WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['username'].'""

mysql_query($sql,$con);
?>
```

Below I have posted my function to call the php sql query:

```
function ChapComp() {
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "chapcomp.php", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
// return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

And I use this button to call the function:

```
<br><a href='#' onclick='ChapComp();'>Complete Chapter One!</a><br>
```

Now when I click the button, nothing happens, the chapter INT value in my database does not change.. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented and it does what you trying to do (checked in chrome) next way:

file1: **view.html** with next contents (you should wellform your html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChapComp() {
 var xmlHttp = null;
 xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlHttp.open( "GET", "chapcomp.php", false );
 xmlHttp.send( null );
}
</script>
<br><a href='#' onclick='ChapComp();'>Complete Chapter One!</a><br>
```

file2: **chapcomp.php** with next contents:

```
<?php
session_start();
// TODO: remove next line
$_SESSION['username'] = 'test';

$con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpassword') or die('Could not connect to mysql server.' );
mysql_select_db('db_name', $con) or die('Could not select database.');

$sql = "UPDATE users
SET chapter= '1'
WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
?>
```

Please Remove

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = 'test';
```

I assume that $_SESSION['username'] is not empty in your case.

Answer (score 1):

As ionutvmi stated you CANNOT run a PHP program of any kind from a browser.

Javascript is used inside your browser (or any other js interpreter for that matter) 
and has nothing to do with the server, which is where you store data (your users table), run php programs and any other server-side related action.

**[Here is a nice post explaining the difference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE users
    SET chapter='1'
    WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"
```

Comment: Check the ' and "'s as well. and username, not $username.

Comment: I implemented that into the site but Im getting a T_STRING error, did I just not type that in correct?

Comment: I edited the post above with the members.php page that i used it on

Comment: dude your function contains not a string, just a statement, which is killing PHP!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you are trying to call a php function using js which is wrong.

If you want to call some php code store it in another file and use javascript to make a request to that file.

P.S.: session_start();  should be placed before any output

Edit: here is a short example

```
function ChapComp()
{
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "somepage.php", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
// return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

where `somepage.php` is the place where you run your sql query

Comment: Im assuming you are reffering to the "<br><a href='#' onclick='ChapComp();'>Complete Chapter One!</a><br>" part? Im sorry Im kinf of new to sessions and such, is there a way you could show me what you mean?

Comment: Oh duh.. I get what you are saying now, so to run the statement i need to call the php using the function?

Comment: exactly, you can't call a function that you defined in php from js the way you did on that page also have a look on some tutorial on how to run sql queries in php

Comment: it will read it either way, but the single quotes should be there

Comment: Okay, so I edited everything above to show what I have now, the problem now is that nothing happens in the database when the button is clicked.. Im not sure if I wrote the sql query function wrong or what.